# Fetch data from an open excel sheet into R?

Tags: r, excel, desctools

I am wondering is it possible to read an excel file that is currently open, and capture things you manually test into R?

I have an excel file opened (in Windows). In my excel, I have connected to a SSAS cube. And I do some manipulations using PivotTable Fields (like changing columns, rows, and filters) to understand the data. I would like to import some of the results I see in excel into R to create a report. (I mean without manually copy/paste the results into R or saving excel sheets to read them later). Is this a possible thing to do in R?

**UPDATE**

I was able to find an answer. Thanks to awesome package created by Andri Signorell.

```
library(DescTools)
fxls<-GetCurrXL()
tttt<-XLGetRange(header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find an answer. Thanks to awesome package created by Andri Signorell.

```
library(DescTools)
fxls<-GetCurrXL()
tttt<-XLGetRange(header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the values you are interested in (in a single spread sheet at a time) to clipboard.

Then

```
dat = read.table('clipboard', header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

Comment: I am looking for a method that doesn't involve manual copying. Is it possible to point R to read results from an excel sheet that is open (results that haven't been saved, in other words, results in memory)

Comment: OK - I interpreted your question as meaning copying and pasting individual values. I'm not aware of anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the final excel spreadsheet as a csv file (comma separated).
Then use read.csv("filename") in R and go from there. Alternatively, you can use read.table("filename",sep=",") which is the more general version of read.csv(). For tab separated files, use sep="\t" and so forth.

I will assume this blog post will be useful: http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/

In the R console, you can type

`?read.table`

for more information on the arguments and uses of this function. You can just repeat the same call in R after Excel sheet changes have been saved.

Comment: I am trying to read an excel in memory file (not a saved one).

Comment: The link I posted contains references to several packages and functions within R that claim to do what you want. RExcel seems like a comprehensive one.

Comment: Hi @Matthew, Thank you very much for pointing out to `RExcel`, it is certainly one way to go. I tried to install `RExcel` on my computer. I have Win 8 (64 bit), and Excel 2013. I did install Excel 2007 in order to get `RExcel`. However, couldn't get the things to running yet.